# GLSL - Drawing 2D UI elements over objects in 3D space

Tags: glsl, billboarding

I posted a similar question earlier but I wasn't specific enough about what I wanted to do.

I have meshes being rendered in 3D space as expected. What I would like to do is display 2D billboarded UI elements over these objects at their 2D positions in screen space, facing the camera like billboards and with uniform scale regardless of the distance to the 3D mesh.

Right now I calculate gl_Position for the meshes like this:

```
gl_Position = projection * (vec4(position, 1.0) * (transformation * inverse(view)));
```

I've tried a couple things, like setting the upper 3x3 portion of the `transformation * inverse(view)` product to the identity:

```
mat4 bbTransformation = transformation * inverse(view)
bbTransformation[0][0] = 1.0;
bbTransformation[0][1] = 0.0;
bbTransformation[0][2] = 0.0;

bbTransformation[1][0] = 0.0;
bbTransformation[1][1] = 1.0;
bbTransformation[1][2] = 0.0;

bbTransformation[2][0] = 0.0;
bbTransformation[2][1] = 0.0;
bbTransformation[2][2] = 1.0;
gl_Position = projection * (vec4(position, 1.0) * bbTransformation)
```

but the final result is slightly offset if the camera is not looking directly at the object, and the 2D elements are still scaled with distance.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

And this is what I want (mocked):

[image]

How can I get the effect I want?

Comment: Do you want the circles to be on top of everything? Or be hidden if an object is in front of the cubes?

Comment: Hi. In principle, if ui shall be on top, you first render 3D with perspective projection, then you render the ui with orthographic projection. It is probably best to use different shader pipelines to tackle this.